# How to link calender widget to website?

Tags: javascript, html

I downloaded a calender widge from site "http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php"
placed all downloaded files on same folder
but not sure how to use the calender in my site

here is the basic code to be displayed

```
<html>
  <head>
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td>to:<script src="calendar.html"></script></td>
         <td>from:<script src="calendar.html"></script></td>
     </tr>

     </table>
   </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

could some please advise how to include it , I am very new your help is much appreciated.

Advanced thx 
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

Basic setup:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="12" id="inputField" />
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
                new JsDatePick({
                    useMode:2,
                    target:"inputField"
                });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6mS3a/

Comment: I just added this to my code but I want two windows like FROM : and TO:  the calender loaded only for one time either for From or TO. how to enable this windown for two textboxes

Comment: Dear @user3346540, I think that before you take on assignments that you have no idea how to perform, especially easy ones like this, you should start by reading a simple manual or book. There are thousands of books and tutorials online to learn anything. That's my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste these 2 lines of code to every page you want the calendar to be available at

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
        /*selectedDate:{                This is an example of what the full configuration offers.
            day:5,                      For full documentation about these settings please see the full version of the code.
            month:9,
            year:2006
        },
        yearsRange:[1978,2020],
        limitToToday:false,
        cellColorScheme:"beige",
        dateFormat:"%m-%d-%Y",
        imgPath:"img/",
        weekStartDay:1*/
    });
};
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    From:<input type="text" size="12" name="from" id="inputField" />
    To: <input type="text" size="12" name="to" id="inputField" />
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just added this to my code but I want two windows like FROM : and TO: the calender loaded only for one time either for From or TO. how to enable this windown for two textboxes